# clonzilla + what the password for debian linux

Tags: root, clonezilla

Please advice what the password in debian Linux (debian Linux in clonezilla software - disaster recovery tool)

Example

I use the clonzilla (backup & restore tool) in order to clone Linux systems

I boot the clonezilla on machine1 and escape to CMD ( from clonzilla ) in order to get debian Linux 
Machine1 - Debian Linux network:

```
 192.168.20.100/24
```

Now I want to copy to my debian Linux some files from other machine -  machine2 ( Linux red-hat 6.X)

Machine2 network:

```
192.168.20.10/24
```

So I do the following on my machine2 in order to copy script.pl to my debian Linux ( machine1 )

```
  scp –rp  /tmp/script.pl  192.168.200.100:/tmp
  root@192.168.20.100's password:
```

please advice what the password for debian Linux ?

Answer (score 3):

If these are your systems, you should know the password. Random people on the Internet surely don't, and even on the off chance that somebody does, what are the odds that they will post your root (system administrator account) password for the world to see?

If these aren't your systems, you either need to ask whoever owns them for the password, or use an account for which you do know the password.

To specify a different user account for scp, you should be able to use the syntax `scp –rp  /tmp/script.pl  someusername@192.168.200.100:/tmp`. Note the `someusername@` part; replace `someusername` with the name of your own user account (or one for which you know the password).

Answer (score 3):

According to:
http://clonezilla.org/clonezilla-live.php , "root" has no password, so you can't login into root account via ssh/scp. Use the "user" account, which has sudo privilege, with the password "live".

Comment: false. whether the root password is set depends on the distribution. for example, Arch Linux sets a root password, but Ubuntu does not. Debian asks you at install-time (although I forget what the default is).

Comment: Tomasz is correct - the root account on the clonezilla live-cd does not have a password.  There are various methods by which it is possible to set a root password (and even start sshd at boot) but by default it has none.